# Convert part element of ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float) to numpy.array

Tags: python, numpy, ctypes

I have a question about convert ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float) to numpy.array

```
float_pointer= ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float)() #100 float data
float_array = numpy.ctypeslib.as_array(float_pointer,shape=(100,)).copy()
```

Above code can covert the whole 100 float data to a numpy.array float_array. Is it possible to convert the 10th to 20th data of float_pointer to a new numpy.array? like

```
float_array = numpy.ctypeslib.as_array(start address of 10th element,shape=(10,)).copy()
```

Answer (score 0):

Listing:

- [[Python.Docs]: ctypes - A foreign function library for Python](https://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes)
- [[NumPy]: Routines](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.html#routines)

You can use slices ([[Python.Docs]: Built-in Types - Common Sequence Operations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations)).

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import ctypes as cts
import sys

import numpy as np


def gen_ctype_ptr(ctype, dim):
    arr = (ctype * dim)(*(ctype(e) for e in range(dim)))
    return cts.cast(arr, cts.POINTER(ctype))


def main(*argv):
    ctype = cts.c_float
    dim = 100
    fp = gen_ctype_ptr(ctype, dim)
    print(fp)
    print(fp[2], fp[dim - 1])
    print(fp[dim])  # !!! Undefined Behavior !!!
    start = 10
    end = 20

    # Method 1:
    arr0 = np.ctypeslib.as_array(fp, shape=(dim,))[start:end].copy()
    # @TODO - cfati: Comment / remove '.copy()' (at the end of the above line),
    #   to see a difference in the (below) results (at the middle of the array).
    # If the pointer is valid until you're done with the array,
    #   you can skip copying to gain some extra speed.
    print("Array 0:", arr0, arr0.dtype, arr0.shape)

    # Method 2:
    arr1 = np.array(fp[start:end], dtype=ctype)
    print("Array 1:", arr1, arr1.dtype, arr1.shape)

    fp[(start + end) // 2] = 99

    print(arr0)
    print(arr1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
                                                   64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.\n")
    sys.exit(rc)
```

**Notes**:

- There are 2 methods listed (both using slices):

  1. Convert the whole pointer data to array and slice it
  2. Create the array by slicing the pointer data (**via a *Python* list**)

I personally prefer the former variant, since it only copies the required amount of memory, and doesn't involve handling (temporary) *Python* objects (which are costly).

**Output**:

> ```
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q075220805]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.10_test0\Scripts\python.exe" ./code00.py
> Python 3.10.9 (tags/v3.10.9:1dd9be6, Dec  6 2022, 20:01:21) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)] 064bit on win32
>
> <__main__.LP_c_float object at 0x0000018D56ED4BC0>
> 2.0 99.0
> 217811481788416.0
> Array 0: [10. 11. 12. 13. 14. 15. 16. 17. 18. 19.] float32 (10,)
> Array 1: [10. 11. 12. 13. 14. 15. 16. 17. 18. 19.] float32 (10,)
> [10. 11. 12. 13. 14. 15. 16. 17. 18. 19.]
> [10. 11. 12. 13. 14. 15. 16. 17. 18. 19.]
>
> Done.
> ```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I know how to solve this issue by use of the 2 methods you have mentioned. I want a method with higher running performance. Method1 needs to convert the whole pointer data first, method2 needs to convert to list first. Actually I want to know if there is way that only convert the data I want directly.  This operation has taken too much running time in my program. I will get a large ctype-pointer(Ex:1000000 elements, every 10000 elements have different meaning, needs to be converted to a standalone numpy.array)

Comment: The 1st method doesn't convert anything, it just generates some array metadata and shares the actual memory area with the pointer. If you tried my 2nd comment you'd know what I mean.

Comment: Thanks, I think the 1st method is the one with better running performance.